# Meteor failing to start

Tags: meteor

I am using the following packages :

```
mrt add bootstrap-3
mrt add iron-router
mrt add angularjs
```

And when i start my application with mrt, i get the following error..

====

```
W2042-20:49:50.746(5.5)? (STDERR) /home/aaa/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W2042-20:49:50.747(5.5)? (STDERR)                       throw(ex);
W2042-20:49:50.747(5.5)? (STDERR)                             ^
W2042-20:49:50.750(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module 'connect'
W2042-20:49:50.750(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
W2042-20:49:50.751(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
W2042-20:49:50.751(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
W2042-20:49:50.751(5.5)? (STDERR)     at require (module.js:380:17)
W2042-20:49:50.751(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Npm.require (/home/aaa/dev/APP/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:87:18)
W2042-20:49:50.752(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/angularjs/server.js:1)
W2042-20:49:50.752(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages/angularjs.js:67:4
W2042-20:49:50.752(5.5)? (STDERR)     at packages/angularjs.js:74:3
W2042-20:49:50.753(5.5)? (STDERR)     at /home/aaa/dev/MEREBAPU/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:154:10
W2042-20:49:50.753(5.5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Comment: Does `npm install connect` work for you?

Comment: yes `npm install connect`works,, also tried all versions,, but still getting exception in code

Answer (score 0):

The angularjs package doesn't work with the version of Meteor that you're using.

The angularjs package is using **meteor_bootstrap**.require to load npm packages, and the new way to do it is Npm.require.

Someone has already filed an [issue](https://github.com/lvbreda/Meteor_angularjs/issues/49) to the Meteor_angularjs team requesting a fix.  Based on their [commit](https://github.com/lvbreda/Meteor_angularjs/commit/6eaa7e97fade8f92a81db75b03e04a6e38b59c2e#diff-78c12f5adc1848d13b1c6f07055d996e) history and the messed up state of their tags, I'd guess that the team thinks they've fixed it but something went wrong.

You can work with the Meteor_angularjs team to get a fix released, or you can install angularjs as a [private package](http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/04/04/meteor-060-brand-new-distribution-system-app-packages-npm-integration).  To do that:

1. Clone the Meteor_angularjs repo under your project's packages directory
2. Modify the Meteor_angularjs code to use the new way to load npm packages, Npm.require and Npm.depends.  You might want to look at the commit I mentioned above - maybe you can just copy that code.
3. Run Meteor.  Meteor will detect the Meteor_angularjs project and install the dependencies

Comment: I have filed that issue. I am unable to understand the fix that you suggested. Did you meant to comment the Npm.require line.

Comment: I updated my answer with details on how to make a private package.  I don't know the exact lines of code that need to be changed - but maybe the commit I mentioned will have them.